# How to set cipherspec preference on Linux for .NET Core applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, .net-core

On Windows, I can edit the Windows group policy to set the preference list of CipherSpecs. How do I achieve the same for .NET Core applications on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Source from github https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14881

.NET respects the system-wide OpenSSL configuration. See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux for more information and for an example of what the configuration file looks like.